# How to email a row in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

First post. I have just started to learn to code (2 days in) but this is way over my head for now.

I want to be able to email the contents of a row (all cells in that row) by right clicking the grey cell that highlights the entire row and then choosing an option in the drop down menu that either allows me to enter an email address or sends to a specific address that is entered into the code (I will always be sending to the same address).

In fact, choosing the option in the drop down menu isn't a necessity, just how I envisage it but any solution that allows me to bypass copying the row and pasting it into an email would work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us your code so we can understand what you have done so far?

Comment: Hey mate.  I have nothing so far.  I have only been learning the basics so far like how to declare variables, the basics of what a function is, syntax and how a computer thinks when you give it instructions.  I wouldn't know where to start atm.  Cheers for the welcome and reply

Comment: See my remark on Web Applications James. Don't re-post on other sites.

Comment: I thought the Web Applications site was totally separate from this site.  If not, my bad.  Cheers for the advice on web applications.  I have done that tutorial before but as far as getting that code to do what I need I have no idea.  I have searched the web a lot on this particular issue

Comment: I'm suggesting baby steps. Try reading the code that deals with reading and writing to a spreadsheet with Google Apps Script. Then you will be able to point us (with code) where exactly you can't go any further. Good luck !!

Comment: Ok, tough love!  Cheers mate, will work on it and then get back with a decent start (maybe even the entire code ;)

Comment: Ok, I have something.  See code below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I know this is probably terrible coding but as I said, until a couple of days ago I had never even read a code, let alone tried to write anything.  So please be nice!

So with some serious googling, copy/pasting, editing for my needs etc and using the very little I know, here is what I have come up with:

```
function onEdit(event){
//transfer a row once specific value entered into a cell within that row (without deleting original row)
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == "Email JM") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
};

function onEditEmail(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i]; 
    var message = row[0] + ", " + row[1] + ", " + row[2] + ", " + row[3]; //whole row
      var subject = "New Order";
    if (row[0] != ""){
      MailApp.sendEmail("example@email.com", subject, message);

    //delete row straight after it is sent    
    sheet.deleteRows(1, 1);
  }

    }
  }
```

Row needing to be emailed is transferred to a different **blank** sheet when I enter "Email JM" at the end of the row and by setting data validation for this column this can be done by clicking the drop down arrow (no typing).  My onEditEmail trigger is set to every minute, which sends all the columns I need from "Sheet2) and then immediately deletes the row so it is not resent a minute later.

The only problem is if 2 orders are entered inside a minute, but this is a very small chance of happening (although I guess it will sooner or later).

Please point out where I can improve this.

Cheers